# Flutter WEB request to local server

Tags: flutter, server, backend, flutter-web

I'm getting a problem, I'm using dio to do http requests, but I get this error, even If I use "http" dependence instead "dio", I had used the ip, localhost and 127.0.0.1 address but none works.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you got

> XMLHttp request error

Is most likely you haven't enabled [CORS: Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) in the backend responses which will let you to access your backend with specified websites.

Since you are using the javascript, You have to set CORS in the backend and tell the backend that you want to send requests from a javascript app.

To enable CORS for every website add this header to the response header in the backend

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

***Origin*** means

> Web content's origin is defined by the scheme (protocol), hostname (domain), and port of the URL used to access it. Two objects have the same origin only when the scheme, hostname, and port all match ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin))

So This will allow **every** website to access your backend and you can change it by replacing `*` with your website address.

#### Other CORS Headers

Also there are bunch of other options to use in the response header and limit incoming requests See [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) docs by Mozilla

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
```

> The Access-Control-Request-Method header notifies the server as part of a preflight request that when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with a POST request method

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-PINGOTHER, Content-Type
```

> The Access-Control-Request-Headers header notifies the server that when the actual request is sent, it will be sent with a X-PINGOTHER and Content-Type custom headers. The server now has an opportunity to determine whether it wishes to accept a request under these circumstances.

```
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

> Finally, Access-Control-Max-Age gives the value in seconds for how long the response to the preflight request can be cached for without sending another preflight request. In this case, 86400 seconds is 24 hours. Note that each browser has a maximum internal value that takes precedence when the Access-Control-Max-Age is greater.